# how to start transition with onclick on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a widget, for this i am using addClass and removeClass method of jquery but some how it is not working please help me with this.

Here is the code:

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('second');
  console.log("hello");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('second');
});
```

```css
   #test {
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }
   .first {
     width: 150px;
     height: 30px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px;
     right: 25px;
   }
   #prop {
     width: 150px;
     height: 30px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px;
     right: 25px;
     background-color: #abc322;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
   }
   .second {
     width: 150px;
     height: 300px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px;
     right: 25px;
     box-shadow: 3px 4px 40px grey;
   }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="first">
  <div id="prop">
    freight Calculator
  </div>
  <p>
    welcome to freight calculator
  </p>
</div>
```

when i click on the div it should change its class and start transition but it is not working. please identify the mistake that i have done.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you wants to remove class on second click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) takes one function as event listener. You can use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead.

```js
$('#prop').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#test').toggleClass('second');
});
```

```css
#test {
  transition : all 0.5s ease;
}
.first {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 25px;
}
#prop {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #abc322;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 25px;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 40px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="first">
  <div id="prop">
    freight Calculator
  </div>
  <p>
    welcome to freight calculator
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @JayTanna I've updated my answer, I hope it will help you

Comment: thank you so much.......!! i am doing this since last 3 hours and you have solved it in a minute......!!!@Muhammad Usman

Comment: when we place text box into div and press enter on it then removes the class '.second'. can please tell me the solution, how to get away from this stuff?? @Muhammad Usman

Comment: @JayTanna Can you provide me a jsFiddle of your current markup?

Comment: when we press enter on textbox some error occures @Muhammad Usman

Comment: @JayTanna https://jsfiddle.net/6y0hf7ob/1/ When you press enter, it submits the form and page reloads and you get error. And further you are calling some functions but you have not defined them in your page.

Comment: sorry, i have just post the half of my code but i don't have called the submitHandler this is why error is occuring..Thank You once again...!!@Muhammad Usman

Answer (score 1):

The `click` method only takes one callback function: the one that should fire on click. You provided two callbacks (one that adds the class and one that removes it). jQuery doesn't know what to do with that, it assumes the first callback is an eventData object and takes the second function as the action to perform on click. This means that on click, all it does is remove the class.

Refer to https://api.jquery.com/click/ to read more about how to use the `click()` method.

If you provide only one callback it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uqmupq3h/

Comment: as the class is added and then we click on any surface it will remove the '.second' class but if i want to remove '.second' class only onClick on '#prop' only How to do it? @Stephan Muller

Comment: Like we have seen in contact us or follow widget on any blogs @Stephan Muller

Answer (score 1):

The [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method only takes one callback function so you should use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('second');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knj0ec6n/

Comment: as the class is added and then we click on any surface it will remove the '.second' class but if i want to remove '.second' class only onClick on '#prop' only How to do it? @Muhammad Usman

Comment: Like we have seen in contact us or follow widget on any blogs @Muhammad Usman